# Inserted Record not getting saved in MS-Access Database through C#.NET 2008

Tags: c#, ms-access

HI,

I am making a Windows Application in C#. NET. When I insert a record in MS-Access Database. It shows that the record is saved, No Errors Occur. But When I reload the project, the record which I added is not found in Database. Please help.

Here is the Code, I am using:

```
DataSet ds13 = new DataSet(); 
OleDbDataReader dr13;
OleDbCommand cmd13 = new OleDbCommand();
cmd13.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
cmd13.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Due_Party VALUES(@A,@B,@C,@D,@E,@F,@G)";    
cmd13.Parameters.Add("@A", SqlDbType.Text).Value = textBox11.Text; 
con.ConnectionString = constr; 
cmd13.Connection = con;
con.Open(); 
cmd13.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
con.Close();
```

Regards
Sunil Kumar

Comment: When you say It shows the record is saved, what do you mean by "It"?, is it you windows application or you DB, please cross-check with your db if the record is actually getting inserted !

Comment: By saying "record is saved", I Mean that when i display the record in my display form (A form, I used to show records of database), record gets displayed. But when I reload the project, then inserted record is not displayed.

Comment: @Sunil Kumar Please edit the question and add your code there with formatting.  It is basically unreadable as a comment.

Comment: Have you debugged and checked?

Comment: @Tarun, I have properly debugged and checked

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the same database file?

Answer (score 2):

How long after the insert are you checking? I only ask because something sticks in my mind about delayed writes when using ADO. But before I go 'a' googling can you let me know

EDIT: Ok it might be the same kind of thing as this

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200300

I know that is talking about ADO and not ADO.Net but the idea might be the same. Does the record show up if you check again later?

Comment: No, when I Re-execute the application, the added record is not displayed.

Comment: Well, there has to be some difference between the 1st and the "re-execution" .. can you try and figure out what it is?